# How to write cucumber json report in HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cucumber, hdfs

I am using cucumber with scala and using below jars

cucumber-junit-1.2.0.jar
cucumber-core-1.2.0.jar
cucumber-html-0.2.3.jar
cucumber-jvm-deps-1.0.3.jar
cucumber-java-1.2.0.jar

i am using cucumber framework in my big data testing, and using spark to read/write/process and data.

i am using cucumber cli.Main method to run my features

```
import cucumber.api.cli.Main

glue = args(0)
gluePath = args(1)
tag = args(2)
tagName = args(3)
val fileNames = args(4)
val arrFileNames = fileNames.split(",")
arrFileNames.foreach(x => sqlContext.sparkContext.addFile(x))
plugin = "-p"
pluginNameAndPath = "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:hdfs:///tmp/target/cucumber-reports/report.html"
pluginNameAndPathJson = "json:hdfs:///tmp/target/cucumber-reports/report.json"
Main.main(  Array(glue,gluePath,tag,tagName,plugin,pluginNameAndPath,plugin,pluginNameAndPathJson,SparkFiles.get("xxx.feature")
```

in the above code when i run in cluster mode it ran successfully but cucumber report not generated in given HDFS location.

But when i run in client mode(without hdfs:/// ) it ran successfully and created cucumber report on the local node.

It seems like cucumber does't have hdfs file system so cannot create the file in hdfs

Can anyone please help how to create cucumber report by giving the hdfs path or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Cucumber is open source. You'll have to put in a feature request and quite possibly implement it yourself.

Comment: Can you help me how to get the cucumber open source code and implementation in it?

Comment: Try Searching Github? Does Cucumber work with OutputStream? That's all you really need

Comment: Thanks all for your comments, Finally i found the solution. Cucumber only work for local files or with http web service only. As we need HDFS file system to write into HDFS. I have provided the local path (i.e. mount path) which is shared by all cluster nodes once the report is generated, use shell script to copy itto hdfs using copyFromLocal.